# React native redux not updating component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to setup redux with react native but it is not updating my components when the store updates.

```
class Dinner extends React.Component {

    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log('does not get called when store update');
    }

    setSelected = (meal) => {
        var index = this.props.selectedDinner.indexOf(meal);

        if (index === -1) {
            console.log('Adding meal to selected: '+meal.name);
            if (this.props.selectedDinner[0] === null) {
                var tempArr = this.props.selectedDinner;
                tempArr[0] = meal;
                this.props.setSelectedDinner(tempArr);

            } else if(this.props.selectedDinner[1] === null)  {
                var tempArr = this.props.selectedDinner;
                tempArr[1] = meal;
                this.props.setSelectedDinner(tempArr);
            } else if(this.props.selectedDinner[2] === null)  {
                var tempArr = this.props.selectedDinner;
                tempArr[2] = meal;
                this.props.setSelectedDinner(tempArr);
            }
        } else {
            console.log("removing meal from selected: "+meal.name)
            var tempArr = this.props.selectedDinner;
            tempArr[index] = null;
            this.props.setSelectedDinner(tempArr);
        }
        LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.easeInEaseOut);
        this.forceUpdate()
    };

    render() {
        return (
          <View style={{flex: 1, width: 360, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', paddingBottom: 20}}>
            <View style={{width: 340, backgroundColor: 'white', justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'center'}}>
              <Text style={{height: 50, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold', flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>Dinner</Text>
              {
                this.props.dinnerFeed.map((prop, key) => 
                  prop === null ?
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{width: 320, height: 120, backgroundColor: 'lightgrey', flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', zIndex: 1, marginBottom: 10, flexShrink: 0}} key={key}><LoadingMealTile /></TouchableOpacity>
                    :
                    (prop === 'none' ? 
                      <TouchableOpacity style={{width: 320, height: 120, backgroundColor: 'lightgrey', flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', zIndex: 1, marginBottom: 10, flexShrink: 0}} key={key}><BlankMealTile /></TouchableOpacity>
                      :
                      this.props.selectedDinner === null || this.props.selectedDinner.indexOf(prop) === null ?
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.setSelected.bind(this, prop)} style={{width: 320, height: 120, backgroundColor: 'lightgrey', flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', zIndex: 1, marginBottom: 10, flexShrink: 0}} key={key}><MealTile selected={-1} name={prop.name} id={prop.id} url={prop.url} key={key}/></TouchableOpacity>
                        :
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.setSelected.bind(this, prop)} style={{width: 320, height: 120, backgroundColor: 'lightgrey', flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', zIndex: 1, marginBottom: 10, flexShrink: 0}} key={key}><MealTile selected={this.props.selectedDinner.indexOf(prop)} name={prop.name} id={prop.id} url={prop.url} key={key}/></TouchableOpacity>
                    )
                )  
              }

              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.loadFeedMeals} style={{width: 320, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'lightgrey', flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', zIndex: 1, marginBottom: 10}}><Text style={{fontSize: 15, }}>Load More Meals</Text></TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }


    function mapStateToProps(state) { 
      return {
           dinnerFeed: state.dinnerFeed,
           selectedDinner: state.selectedDinner,
      }
    };

    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
      return {
        setDinnerMeals: (dinnerMeals) => dispatch(setDinnerMeals(dinnerMeals)),
        setSelectedDinner: (selectedDinner) => dispatch(setSelectedDinner(selectedDinner)),

      }
    };

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dinner);
```

The function setSelectedDinner correctly changes the redux store, but the component doesn't call its componentDidUpdate function

edit:Here is the reducer code

```
    export default (state, action) => {
        console.log(action);
        switch (action.type) {
            case "SET-SELECTED-DINNER":
                return {
                        ...state,
                        selectedDinner: action.selectedDinner
                  };
            default:
                return state;
        }
    };
```

I believe this code shouldn't mutate the state directly because i have used this reducer for redux on a reactjs project

Comment: Can you please add your reducer code that handles the setSelectedDinner action.
Such issues are often caused by incorrect reducers that mutate the state.

Comment: As an unrelated aside, I recommend that you look at using selectors inside mapStateToProps instead of directly accessing state properties.

Comment: sorry for the delay getting back to this. The problem is related to your reducer and how you pass around the selectedDinner object. See my edits below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most common cause of Redux state being updated, but of connected components not updating is mutating state within the reducer. A very similar common problem is not recognising that the Redux connect HoC performs a shallow comparison.

This is because Redux checks for changes by using object equality. (if a `===` comparison returns true, the object is considers to have not changed.)

Consider the following **incorrect** reducer:

```
function todoApp(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER:
      return state.visibilityFilter = action.filter;
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Since the reducer above mutated the state, no updated is triggered.

A correct example (taken from the [Redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers)) is shown below:

```
function todoApp(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        visibilityFilter: action.filter
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

### Shallow comparison

As well as the above best practice of not mutating state but always returning a new state for anything that changes, it is important to remember that Redux connect is using this shallow comparison for all objects returned by `mapStateToProps`.

Consider a simplified version of your `mapStateToProps` function:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) { 
    return {
        selectedDinner: state.selectedDinner,
    }
};
```

And now consider how you are passing selected dinner to your `setSelectedDinner` action (again simplified):

```
setSelected = (meal) => {
    var index = this.props.selectedDinner.indexOf(meal);

    // when index === -1 we need to add this meal
    if (index === -1) {     
        // there is no meal at index 0 so we add it                    
        if (this.props.selectedDinner[0] === null) {
            // NOTICE - the line below still references selected dinner in state!
            var tempArr = this.props.selectedDinner;
            tempArr[0] = meal;

            // NOTICE - we are calling setSelectedDinner with the same object
            // that comes from state! 
            this.props.setSelectedDinner(tempArr);
        }
    }
}
```

So the problem is, that in your reducer function you are replacing the selectedDinner object with itself, so Redux sees no updates.

The quickest change that will fix your problem is to modify the reducer function to read (the slice call clones your array):

```
export default (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SET-SELECTED-DINNER":
            return {
                    ...state,
                    selectedDinner: action.selectedDinner.slice()
              };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

There are lots of other small changes that would make this code easier to work with and less prone to such bugs. Two simple ones are:

1. Move the logic that modifies your selectedDinner array out of the component, and place it in the reducer.
2. Introduce selectors

Comment: I've edit it so it has my reducer. It should work the same, but i will try this solution aswell

Comment: @ryan I can't seem to find the place where you call the setSelectedDinner action from your components. Have you added your full component code? Is your setSelected component function missing?

Comment: I didn't think it was necessary but I've added it incase it helps :D

Comment: Shouldn't the temp array that i pass to setSelectedDinner be slightly different because the value of the array at index 0 is different from the states value at index 0?

Comment: The problem is that since redux (or react) is performing a shallow comparison, all that it sees is that the array is the same object. Changing the contents of the array don't change the object. That is why cloning your array with slice fixes the problem. The clone is a new object.

Comment: You can hit related performance issues with redux due to this but from the other side - the content of an array is identical but because the array is not the same object, redux and react re render unnecessarily

Comment: Thank you so much for you help this worked perfectly :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to pass current timestamp when you are updating your default state in redux. this will make some change in current state and your response in class is changed.